# Rewrites breaking links

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I created a URL rewrite for my blog but all the links such as css, href & javascript are broken due to this.

Without manually continuing to rename all the links by adding a / before each link, would there be anyway to rewrite it within the .htaccess file somehow? Here is what i have:

```
RewriteRule ^blog/([-a-zA-Z0-9]+)/?$ blog.php?title=$1 [L,NC]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By adding the extra `/` in your URL, the browser doesn't know what the relative URL base is, so it's appending `/blog/` in front of *every* relative URL link that you have in your page content. The browser doesn't know that it's actually getting content from `/blog.php`, which sits in the document root, not in what appears (to the browser, at least) to be a folder called "blog".

Instead of changing all of your links, you can add a base URI to the header of your page:

```
<base href="/" />
```

Note that in some cases (I think with old IE browsers), you need the full URL:

```
<base href="http://your-site.com/" />
```

Comment: Wow! You learn new things everyday. Been studying html for years now and never realized there was base! Helped me with 2 questions today, thanks buddy keep it up. :)

Answer (score 0):

With `mod_rewrite`, you can check if your URL point on a file :

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
```

Or a folder :

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
```

Here's the `.htaccess` you may use :

```
# if this url doesn't point on a file...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
# ...and doesn't point on a folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# ...then check this rule
RewriteRule ^blog/([-a-zA-Z0-9]+)/?$ blog.php?title=$1 [L,NC]
```